# Hidden Icons Window In Windows 7 Occupying 50% Of The Screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, icons, desktop

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise and for the last few months, whenever I select the 'Show Hidden Icons' button in the bottom-right corner of the taskbar, the window that appears on screen is **huge** - taking up almost 50% of the screen (see screengrab below); previously, this window only occupied a very small section in the bottom right-hand corner screen. Has anyone any idea how to resolve this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Look for an icon with a very long shortcut name. Lenovo Mouse icon is many characters wide and it need to reduce to to about a dozen characters.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the "show hidden icons" window and mine was also HUGE! (With very small icons).  While window was active and mouse cursor within the window, I held the "Windows" key down and used the minus (-) button to shrink the window to desired size.

Comment: Are you sure, because in Windows 10, it resizes the desktop